# Is it possible to capture information from network tab to a text file by building a chrome plugin

Tags: google-chrome, plugins, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, google-chrome-app

I'm trying to access the information within the network tab for automation purposes.

My requirement is to capture the information available in the network in a text file so i can use that data.

I found out the way to do it manually. for this we have to go to network tab and right click and select save as HAR content so this will be saved to file

Now i want to do this automatically so I decided to build a plugin which can save the network tab content to a text file. Is it possible to save this information to text file using java?

Also please tell me any other approaches to capture this information

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do it in a chrome extension using [chrome.devtools.network.getHAR](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools_network#method-getHAR):

```js
function saveAs(arr, name, mime) {
    var blob = new window.Blob(arr, { type: mime || 'text/plain;charset=utf-8' });
    var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = url;
    link.download = name || 'save.txt';
    link.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click'));
}
chrome.devtools.network.getHAR(function(log) {
    var json = JSON.stringify(log, null, '\t');
    saveAs([json], 'har.json', 'text/json;charset=utf-8');
});
```